# Email Funcionality in salesforce

Tags: apex, email

I have written an apex class to send email from salesforce. The issue i am facing here is when i receive email i can see the sender name as

```
   noreply@salesforce.com
```

I want  to change it to my organization email address. Is it possible.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to set From Adress in Apex is to use setOrgWideEmailAddressId(ID)  method:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setOrgWideEmailAddressId

Something like that(it is not working code):

```
 OrgWideEmailAddress[] orgEmailAdresses = [SELECT  Id
                               FROM OrgWideEmailAddress 
                               WHERE Address = 'Your Adress'];
 if(orgEmailAdresses.isEmpty() || orgEmailAdresses.size() != 1){
     // throw some exception 
 }                              

 Messaging.SingleEmailMessage m = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
 m.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgEmailAdresses[0].Id);
```